# Uploading file via form into GAE from Android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, blobstore

I have an app on GAE at: http://1.myawesomecity.appspot.com/

FIXED:

```
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://1.myawesomecity.appspot.com/");
                http_client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                String result = EntityUtils.toString( http_client.execute(post).getEntity(), "UTF-8");
                String actualURL = result.substring(result.indexOf("http://"), result.indexOf("\" method"));
                Log.w("asdf", "url " + actualURL );


                post = new HttpPost(actualURL);
                http_client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);                    
                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );
                String mime_type = "image/png";
                File file = new File( filename ); //context.getFilesDir(), 
                entity.addPart( "myFile", new FileBody( file, mime_type));
                post.setEntity( entity );

                String res = EntityUtils.toString( http_client.execute(post).getEntity(), "UTF-8");
                Log.w("asdf", res);
```

The above grabs the ACTUAL upload URL from the GAE server, and passes in the file as dictated by the CORRECT answer below.

Old Question:

As you can see, if you choose a file and hit submit, it will 404, but the file actually does get stored (as long as it is not too big, < 100kb). Don't type in anything in the first text field.

Now, putting aside how this particular app is barely functional, I'm trying to upload a file from Android onto this server.

The site's upload script uses blobstore, and the file field's name is "myFile".

Now in my Android app, I have:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(<my app's url>);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myFile", <path to a file selected by user> ) );
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

This throws an exception.

How is this any different from me going to my site through a browser, choosing a file, and hitting submit? Why does going through a browser actually go through with uploading the file, when the Android code does not?

I know that my filepath is valid. Is there something I'm doing wrong? or is clicking on "submit" from a browser different from executing a httpclient from Android?

Comment: What exception does it throw? Please post stacktrace.

Comment: Please google that. Know why NetworkOnMainThreadException  happens then you should find your answer.

Comment: I've changed it (back) to an AsyncThread. It does not throw an exception. For whatever reason, I just had to wait a very long time for the background process to run. Either way, it seems as though my file is not being uploaded.

When filling out a form for a file through the browser, is the form filled out as the file's directory in the local machine? If this were the case, I can't see why my current asyncthread cannot upload the file. . .

And there's no way to pass in an actual File object to the form is there?

I can't figure out why going through the browser works, but not from Android.

Comment: In other words, is clicking "choose file" and choosing a file the same as setting the namevaluepair myFile to a local Android file directory?

And is clicking 'submit' the same as doing httpconnection.execute(httppost)?

If either of the true are false, the explanation should point to why my code is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploading file to a blobstore on GAE is a two step process:

1. first you need to get a proper URL where to POST your data, usually people use something like "/bloburl" handler for that purpose
2. when you have blob upload URL, you use it in your request.
3. the file you send does not go as `NameValuePair`, it's supposed to go as a `MultiPartEntity`.

here's the code that works (you'll need apache http library for MultiPartEntry support):

```
DefaultHttpClient http_client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet http_get = new HttpGet(Config.BASE_URL + "bloburl");
HttpResponse response = http_client.execute(http_get);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
String first_line = reader.readLine();
Log.w(TAG, "blob_url: " + first_line);

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(first_line);
http_client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );

mime_type = "application/zip";
File file = new File( context.getFilesDir(), filename );
entity.addPart( "file", new FileBody( file, mime_type));
post.setEntity( entity );

String result = EntityUtils.toString( http_client.execute(post).getEntity(), "UTF-8");
Log.i(TAG, result);
```

Comment: Could you explain what that first http_get/client is doing? Looks like it's somehow grabbing the proper upload URL but why is this necessary / wanted?

Comment: ^_^ you sir are a genius. I see now that the first http_get grabs the ACTUAL upload url.