# difference between filling out a http form from a browser and using httppost in Android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, http, blobstore

I have an app on GAE at: http://1.myawesomecity.appspot.com/

As you can see, if you choose a file and hit submit, it will 404, but the file actually does get stored (as long as it is not too big, < 100kb). Don't type in anything in the first text field.

The file's post name is "myFile".

I'm now trying to upload files from an Android app using httppost.

The user selects a file and I get its directory, and set the namevaluepair of myFile to the file directory.
I then execute the httpconnection, but the file does NOT get uploaded.

So my questions are.. what are the differences between

1. going on a browser, clicking "choose file", and selecting a file vs assigning myFile in the  namevaluepair to the file's directory

   and
2. clicking "submit" to start the upload vs running httpconnection.execute(httppost)?

If there are no differences, the file should upload. The file is NOT being uploaded, so I believe knowing the differences between the two processes (browser vs httppost) should reveal why the file is not being uploaded.

I am certain of the following: my file directory is correct. The server itself (though barely functional) DOES allow uploading through a browser, whether from my PC's browser, Android emulator's browser, or even from an actual Android machine's browser. The Android app's httpconnection is going through (no exceptions are thrown when I execute the httpconnection).

FYI, the server is using GAE's blobstore.

The Android code:

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url); //url is the app's site listed above

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myFile", filename) ); //filename is the file's path
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                
        httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: I'm going to assume the server code is not necessary as it functions from a browser.

Comment: Your Android code simply send the file name to server, to upload the file, you need get the file content and write to the upstream (this is also how browser works behind the scene). There are several way to do this, one from the answer in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317270/uploading-file-via-form-into-gae-from-android).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to actually send the file, not just the filename. Something as simple as the following should do that for you:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost post = new HttpPost( url );
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );

entity.addPart( "theFile", new FileBody((( new File( filename ), mimeType ));

post.setEntity( entity );

client.execute( post );
```